# How to speed up myLocation determination

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the new `API V2`, but that's probably not important since I am newbie for maps anyway:)
I have very simple need. I want to show my location and one target marker and all is working. It's just that the my location determination is not predictable, can get minutes or so to get the blue circle.
What I thought is to manually use the `LocationManager` to retreive in background the coarse or fine location and pass that value to the `Mapactivity`. Since normally the map activity will not start immediatelly it would work nice. Then I could also save to databse the last location and pass that in the case the map activity starts before the `LocationManager` get the real location.

I am looking at the api's but could not find a function that would display imemdiatelly the blue circle at given LatLong. Is this function available?
If this function is not available the only workaround that I could find is to override `onlocationchanged` to retrieve the new location and save the last, and to display the marker on last known mylocation (that would hide automatically itself on first locationchanged event).

But it would be easier, and also pretier, if I could simply pass initial mylocaltion coordiantes?

Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking at the api's but could not find a function that would display imemdiatelly the blue circle at given LatLong. Is this function available?

Use `setLocationSource()` to provide a `LocationSource` to the `GoogleMap`. Once your `LocationSource` is called with `activate()`, you will be handed a listener object, to which you can pass `Location` objects for the readings you get from a location provider.

Comment: Thanks. I have followed the LocationSourceDemoActivity from the sample maps app and I am reporting here in case some needs. It is simple. Do as the

Comment: follows. In the activate function set the location as it is shown in onMapLongClick. Then it is important to deactivate the listener and to reset the listener to default with mMap.setLocationSource(null) so that the real location is refreshed.